# What is the solution for this?

Tags: integration

I know that the bold 1 refers to the indicator function. However, how do I interpret the subscript [0,1]? Can someone compute the integral, including steps so that I can properly understand how the bold 1 works.

$\int_{0}^{3}x\mathbf{1}_{[1,2]}(x)dx$

Comment: $\mathbf 1_{[1,2]}=1$ if $x\in[1,2]$ and $=0$ otherwise

Answer (score 2):

This is an "*indicator function*".  $\textbf{1}_{A}(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x\in A\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

The bracket notation is standard notation for intervals.  $[1,2]=\{x\in \Bbb R~:~1\leq x\leq 2\}$.  Square braces imply the corresponding endpoint is included while parentheses imply it is not.  These can be mixed, for instance $[3,7) = \{x\in\Bbb R~:~3\leq x<7\}$

---

As for your specific integral... noting that the integrand is equal to zero outside of the interval $[1,2]$ we have

$$\int\limits_0^3x\textbf{1}_{[1,2]}(x)dx = \int\limits_1^2 xdx=\left[\frac{x^2}{2}\right]^{x=2}_{x=1}=\frac{2^2}{2}-\frac{1^2}{2}=1.5$$